# How to flatten all brackets (i.e. to get separated elements as output)?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have `a = {1, 2, 3}`, and want to obtain `Multinomial[1, 2, 3]`, which is `60`.

But when I input `Multinomial[a]`, the input `a` is the entire list so I got `{1, 1, 1}`. That is, I need to separate `a` from a single list into separated elements so that I can input them correctly.

`Multinomial[Flatten[a]]` also doesn't work, since the last bracket can't be removed by `Flatten`. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: `Multinomial @@ a`, which in full form would be `Apply[Multinomial][a]` or `Apply[Multinomial, a]`: look up [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html). Think of `Apply` as changing the head of an expression, in this case from `List` to `Multinomial`. Tangentially, the arguments to `Multinomial` should be a [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html).

Comment: For completeness, since you are changing the head, you could also use `a /. List -> Multinomial` However, solution provided by @MarcoB is preferrable.

Comment: Thanks. Tried all these methods and solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to calculate Multinomial on the following list:

```
list={1,2,3};
```

Use:

```
Multinomial@@list
```